# CollectionView vs TableView (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, swift3

I have two classes that do exactly the same thing, load places of a chosen category near the user's location but one uses a collectionView and the other uses a tableView (and a particular animation).

I added only the part of code that serves the question, and although some names are different, all links with the storyboards and other classes are the same as you can see much of the code is very similar between these two classes.

My problem is that the class with collectionView work perfectly, but the class using the tableView does not show the cells of the tableView (as if it did not load it properly) if anyone could see if there is a mistake, I would be grateful.

This is the class using the collectionView :

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import AVFoundation

private let reuseIdentifier = "PlacesCell"

extension UIViewController {
    func present(viewController : UIViewController, completion : (() -> ())? = nil ){
        if let presented = self.presentedViewController {
            presented.removeFromParentViewController()
        }
        self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: completion)
    }
}

class NearbyPlacesViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var locationManager:CLLocationManager?

    let minimumSpacing : CGFloat = 15 //CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)
    let cellWidth: CGFloat = 250
    let radius = 5000 // 5km
    var category : QCategory?
    var currentLocation : CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    var places: [QPlace] = []

    var isLoading = false
    var response : QNearbyPlacesResponse?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //self.collectionView
        self.title = category?.name

        collectionView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 0, left: minimumSpacing, bottom: 0, right: minimumSpacing)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        determineMyCurrentLocation()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        category?.markView()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func canLoadMore() -> Bool {
        if isLoading {
            return false
        }

        if let response = self.response {
            if (!response.canLoadMore()) {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }

    func loadPlaces(_ force:Bool) {

        if !force {
            if !canLoadMore() {
                return
            }
        }

        print("load more")
        isLoading = true
        NearbyPlacesController.getNearbyPlaces(by: category?.name ?? "food", coordinates: currentLocation!, radius: radius, token: self.response?.nextPageToken, completion: didReceiveResponse)
    }

    func didReceiveResponse(response:QNearbyPlacesResponse?, error : Error?) -> Void {
        if let error = error {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let actionDismiss = UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            let actionRetry = UIAlertAction(title: "Retry", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.loadPlaces(true)
                }
            })
            alertController.addAction(actionRetry)
            alertController.addAction(actionDismiss)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.present(viewController: alertController)
            }
        }
        if let response = response {
            self.response = response
            if response.status == "OK" {
                if let placesDownloaded = response.places {
                    places.append(contentsOf: placesDownloaded)
                }

                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            } else {
                let alert = UIAlertController.init(title: "Error", message: response.status, preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Retry", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.loadPlaces(true)
                    }
                }))
                self.present(viewController: alert)
            }
            isLoading = false
        }
        else {
            print("response is nil")
        }
    }

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return places.count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! PlacesCell

        let place = places[indexPath.row]
        cell.update(place: place)

        if indexPath.row == places.count - 1 {
            loadPlaces(false)
        }

        return cell
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "maps-vc", sender: indexPath)
    }

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayoutDelegate

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return minimumSpacing
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let cellPadding: CGFloat = 20.0
        let columnWidth:CGFloat = cellWidth
        let imageWidth = columnWidth
        let labelWidth = columnWidth - cellPadding * 2

        let photoHeight = heightForPhotoAtIndexPath(indexPath: indexPath, withWidth: imageWidth)
        let annotationHeight = heightForAnnotationAtIndexPath(indexPath: indexPath, withWidth: labelWidth)
        let height = photoHeight + annotationHeight

        return CGSize.init(width: columnWidth, height: height)
    }

    // Calculates the height of photo
    func heightForPhotoAtIndexPath(indexPath: IndexPath,
                                   withWidth width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {

        var size = CGSize.init(width: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT), height: 1)
        let place = places[indexPath.row]

        guard let photo = place.photos?.first, place.photos?.first?.photoRef != nil else {
            return 0
        }

        size = CGSize.init(width: CGFloat(photo.width!), height: CGFloat(photo.height!))

        let boundingRect =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT))
        let rect  = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: size, insideRect: boundingRect)

        return rect.size.height
    }

    // Calculates the height label
    func heightForAnnotationAtIndexPath(indexPath: IndexPath, withWidth width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {

        let place = places[indexPath.row]
        let annotationPadding = CGFloat(5)

        let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
        let commentHeight = place.heightForComment(font, width: width)

        let height = annotationPadding + commentHeight + annotationPadding

        return height
    }

    // did receive location

    func didReceiveUserLocation(_ userLocation:CLLocation) {
        currentLocation = userLocation.coordinate

        loadPlaces(true)
    }        
     // MARK: - Navigation

     // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
     override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "maps-vc" && sender is IndexPath {
            let dvc = segue.destination as! MapViewController
            dvc.index = (sender as! IndexPath).row
            dvc.places = places
            dvc.userLocation = currentLocation
        }
     }
}
```

This is the class using the tableView:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
import GoogleMaps
import GooglePlaces
import Social
import AVFoundation

private let resueIdentifier = "MyTableViewCell"

extension UIViewController {
    func present(viewController : UIViewController, completion : (() -> ())? = nil ){
        if let presented = self.presentedViewController {
            presented.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
                self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: completion)
            })
        } else {
            self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: completion)
        }
    }
}

class CourseClass2: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var locationManager:CLLocationManager?
    let minimumSpacing : CGFloat = 15 //CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)
    let cellWidth: CGFloat = 250
    let radius = 5000 // 5km
    var category : QCategoryy?
    var currentLocation : CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    var places: [QPlace] = []
    var isLoading = false
    var response : QNearbyPlacesResponse?
    var rows = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = category?.name
}

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        determineMyCurrentLocation()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        rows = 0
        insertRowsMode3()
        tableView.reloadData()
        category?.markView()
}
    @IBAction func refreshTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        rows = 0
        insertRowsMode3()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func canLoadMore() -> Bool {
        if isLoading {
            return false
        }
        if let response = self.response {
            if (!response.canLoadMore()) {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }

    func loadPlaces(_ force:Bool) {

        if !force {
            if !canLoadMore() {
                return
            }
        }

        print("load more")
        isLoading = true
        NearbyPlaces.getNearbyPlaces(by: category?.name ?? "food", coordinates: currentLocation!, radius: radius, token: self.response?.nextPageToken, completion: didReceiveResponse)
    }

    func didReceiveResponse(response:QNearbyPlacesResponse?, error : Error?) -> Void {
        if let error = error {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let actionDismiss = UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            let actionRetry = UIAlertAction(title: "Retry", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.loadPlaces(true)
                }
            })
            alertController.addAction(actionRetry)
            alertController.addAction(actionDismiss)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.present(viewController: alertController)

            }
        }
        if let response = response {
            self.response = response
            if response.status == "OK" {
                if let placesDownloaded = response.places {
                    places.append(contentsOf: placesDownloaded)
                }

                self.tableView?.reloadData()
            } else {
                let alert = UIAlertController.init(title: "Error", message: response.status, preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Retry", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.loadPlaces(true)
                    }
                }))
                 self.present(viewController: alert)
            }
            isLoading = false
        }
        else {
            print("response is nil")
        }
    }
    func insertRowsMode2() {

        tableView.beginUpdates()
        for i in 0..<places.count {
            insertRowMode2(ind: i, usr: places[i])
        }
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }

    func insertRowMode2(ind:Int,usr:QPlace) {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        let indPath = IndexPath(row: ind, section: 0)

        rows = ind + 1
      tableView.insertRows(at: [indPath], with: .right)
       tableView.endUpdates()
    }

    func insertRowsMode3() {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        rows = 0

        insertRowMode3(ind: 0)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
    func insertRowMode3(ind:Int) {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        let indPath = IndexPath(row: ind, section: 0)
        rows = ind + 1
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indPath], with: .right)

        guard ind < places.count-1 else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.20) {

            self.insertRowMode3(ind: ind+1)
        }
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return  places.count    /*  rows   */
    }
    public  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell

        let place = places[indexPath.row]
        cell.update(place: place)

        if indexPath.row == places.count - 1 {
            loadPlaces(false)
        }

        return (cell)
    }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
    })

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToLast" , sender: indexPath.row)
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {

            places.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

        }
    }
    func didReceiveUserLocation(_ userLocation:CLLocation) {
        currentLocation = userLocation.coordinate

        loadPlaces(true)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "goToLast" && sender is IndexPath {

            let dvc = segue.destination as! FinalClass
            dvc.index = (sender as! IndexPath).row
            dvc.places = places
            dvc.userLocation = currentLocation

            }
        }

    @IBAction func IndTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
```

Comment: Well you are defining the ruseIdentifier as "MyTableViewCell" and in your cellForRowAt as "cell" maybe there is your problem? And did you set the DataSource right?

Comment: @DennisWeidmann "cell" is the identifier of the table view cell and "MyTableViewCell" is the custom class of the table view cell

Comment: If you add breakpoints to some of the table view data source methods are they getting hit? Is `tableView` connected? If you are building this with Xcode 9 have if left the main thread checker option turned on in the scheme? If the main thread checker is on are you getting any console messages about accessing the UI off the main thread?

Comment: @theMikeSwan yes tableView is connected and i do not get any console messages from main thread checker, can you suggest to me where i can try to add the breakpoints?

Comment: I would add breakpoints that automatically continue after evaluation to `numberOfSections`, `numberOfRowsInSection`, & `cellForRowAt` all with an action to log a message with the name of the method. That way you will know if they are even getting called. If they are then take a look at what the last two of those methods is returning (maybe `places.count` is `0` when the method gets called for some reason or the cell is coming out empty)

Comment: In your viewWillDisappear, u r calling viewWillAppear...it has nothing to do with ur question, just said...

Comment: Please check with some dummy data if your cells are getting loaded properly...

Comment: @theMikeSwan i tried, cellForRowAt is not called

Comment: @seran, if `numberOfSections` and `numberOfRowsInSection` are both getting called but not `cellForRowAt` then `numberOfRowsInSection` must be returning `0`. Set the breakpoint in `numberOfRowsInSection` to stop when triggered and look at what is in `places`, it should turn out to be empty. Provided it does find the place where `places` is populated or changed and add a call to reload the table view right after (wrapped in `DispatchQueue.main.async { }`) and it should work better.

Comment: @theMikeSwan i find out that without the method insertRowMode[2-3] the tableView works well

Comment: (the methods i use for the animation)

Comment: That may have something to do with the fact that you are calling the methods to begin and end updates on the table view twice. See what happens if you remove the begin and end updates calls from the singular versions of you insert row methods.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the CourseClass2 class as the delegate/dataSource for your tableView?

Try adding

```
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.delegate = self
```

to your viewDidLoad method.

Almost every time I run into an issue like yours is because I forgot to set the delegate or dataSource.

Edit: I had previously only added the delegate on my answer, thanks Dennis for reminding me of the dataSource.

Comment: I guess you meant tableView.dataSource not tableView.delegate right?

Answer (score 0):

I saw your are doing an async update, but a synced reloadData...

You will have to do the update inside the asyncAfter, or add a closure to your insertRowMode3 and reloadData in that closure...

Could you try this?

```
func insertRowMode3(ind:Int) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.20) {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: it didn't work, the strange thing is that even animation does not start, in theory when loading the page the cells of the tableView should appear one after the other depending on how many are the results and instead I find the tableView with the cells all already extras and empty

Comment: And you have added the dataSource as answered above in viewDidLoad too? Also you have data inside your array before reloadingData? Could you please check the count of your array before updating?

Comment: yes i did, i can try to add some break points? where you suggest me to add the break points ?